# Getting an error while creating a briefcase on BeeWare

Tags: python-3.x, wix, beeware

[The WIX environment variable does not point to an install of the WiX Toolset.
Current value: WindowsPath('.')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzBmX.png)

Comment: Is the WiX Toolset installed? https://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close the terminal you're working on.
2. Install WIX toolkit form https://wixtoolset.org/
3. Install via GUI installer.
4. Make sure it has been added to your system variable path. (refer picture below)
5. Run briefcase create.

Hope this helps :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While creating briefcase in BeeWare, you should have admin access because it downloads and install packages. 
This issue is coming because briefcase is unable to download Wix Toolset and unable to point out Wix environment variable.

You can manually download Wix Toolset from here https://wixtoolset.org/releases/
install it and check your environment variables in system variables you can find Wix.

Now try to create briefcase after installation.